# Массив данных с типом структуры

Tags: массивы, golang, golang-struct

Есть структура:

```
type Coord struct { 
    x, y int
}
```

И есть функция

```
metod.LinConMetMain(n)
```

Она возвращает массивы `[]int і []float64`
Вопрос, как присвоить полю Х массива

```
N := make([]Coord, n)
```

значения функции?

```
N.x, _ = metod.LinConMetMain(n) //это не работает :D
```

Comment: Нет ))  
N[0].x = [0]int  
N[1].x = [1]int  
и так дале

Comment: :( не хочу цикл